# Click an image on a VBA userform to open a PDF file

Tags: vba, pdf

I want to click a picture (A question mark) on a Word VBA userform and have an associated PDF file (helpful tips) open. The user could read the file and then close it and be taken back to the userform to finish filling it out. The folks at the Microsoft Community suggested:

```vb
Private Sub Picture_Click()
Dim filePath as String
filePath="Z:\EGS\Templates\EGS Proposal Comm-SLED Quote Only\EGS Tech Note - Quote-Only Proposals.pdf"
Shell "cmd/c start " & CHr(34) & filePath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

But this keeps saying it can't find the file (I have repeatedly checked the path to make sure there were no typo errors).

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: First thing I see is a missing blank between `cmd` and  `/c`

Answer (score 0):

One way to open your PDF file would be to use WScript like that

```
Sub openPDF()

    Dim oShell, sFile
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    sFile = "<your filename>"
    oShell.Run sFile

End Sub
```

**Update** In order to make sure that the file exists the following code will check for that

```
Sub openPDF()
    Dim oShell
    Dim sFile
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    sFile = "<your filename>"
    
    If FileExists(sFile) Then
        oShell.Run sFile
    Else
        MsgBox "File does not exist", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Filename"
    End If

End Sub

Function FileExists(ByVal file As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = False
    FileExists = Dir(file) <> ""
End Function
```

Comment: tried above in Word VBA with

Comment: tried above in Word VBA with Private Sub QuestionMark_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Dim oShell, sFile
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
sFile = "Z:\EGS\Templates\EGS Proposal Comm-SLED Quote Only\EGS Tech Note - Quote-Only Proposals.pdf"
oShell.Run sFile

End Sub
but only get run-time error of '-2147024894 (80070002)' Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed.

Comment: I googled a bit and the error you get is probably saying FILE NOT FOUND. Try another file without any blanks in the path an re-check. If this works, your file name probably contains too many or too less blanks.

Comment: I tested and I get the same error in case the file name is wrong.  I really think you have a type in your file name, probaly something to do with  _white space_ .

Comment: Did you test my modified code? You should also test with a local file! And what kind of rights do you have on the network drive? Code works for me also on a network drive where I only have read access.

Comment: Yes, you were correct - my fumble fingers mistyped (pesky "ohs" look like "zeros" ) and I kept not seeing it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built in [FollowHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.followhyperlink?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158007431)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method. It will open the pdf with the default registered app.

```
ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink yourFilePath
```

Comment: TriedPrivate Sub QuestionMark_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="Z:\EGS\Templates\Test.pdf", _
    NewWindow:=True
End Sub
Get a 4198 Error - Command failed.

Comment: Again, I really think, that the file name is not correct. I edited my answer and added a function which will check if the file exists. BTW, what kind of drive is `Z:`?

Comment: It's a network drive.

Comment: Did you test my modified code?